# Batch file call VBS with "quoted spaces" in argument

Tags: file, batch-file, parameters, spaces

I am trying to create a batch file to restart multiple computers from a TXT file. Everything works fine as long as the /c "comment here" parameter has no spaces. If I pass "Testing" as the comment, I get "Testing" in the pop-up for the restart, as expected. If I pass "Testing spaces" as the comment, I still only get "Testing" in the pop-up. With @echo off, I have verified the comment retains the spaces when it is passed to VBS, so I think the problem is that I am running through an "invisible.vbs" script to prevent another CMD window from opening and hanging the original BAT script.

I would like to be able to have a final command run similar to:

shutdown /r /m \\127.0.0.1 /t 120 /c "Your computer will shut down for maintenance tasks in two minutes"

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

The essential part of restart.bat:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%c in (%FilePath%) do WScript /nologo "%windir%\myscripts\invisible.vbs" "shutdown /r /m \\%%c /t %delay% /c %message%"
```

I have also tried adding extra quotes around %message% with no success:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%c in (%FilePath%) do WScript /nologo "%windir%\myscripts\invisible.vbs" "shutdown /r /m \\%%c /t %delay% /c "%message%""
```

The invisible.vbs script (found on StackExchange):

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Using your third method suggested, I am getting a script error:

```
Script:    C:\Windows\myscripts\invisible.vbs
Line:      1
Char:      46
Error:     The system cannot find the file specified
Code:      80070002
Source:    (null)
```

EDIT 2: I just tried the first method also, and I now get a vbscript echo pop-up with the correct command that I wish to be sent, but the command is not sent. I am far from a programmer, and the only VBS I have used is stuff I have found online. I do appreciate the help you have offered so far, but I still can't get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do it. The logic behind the `Arguments` object in WScript seems to remove quotes.

So, i can think in at least three alternatives

1) The most simple: use another character as an indicator of a quote and replace it with quote in the vbs script

```
cmd code : cscript myscript.vbs "shutdown /r /m \\%%c /t %delay% /c '%message%'"
vbs code : WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run replace(WScript.Arguments(0),"'",""""), 0, False
```

The only problem with it is at some point, probably, you will need to use the placeholder character as a real character.

2) The most complex: use wmi to retrieve the current process id and from here retrieve the original command line of the script. A lot of code, if interested, here at StackOverflow there are some nice samples.

3) The easy, fast, and unusual. Use environment variables. Save the command into a variable and pass the name of the variable to the script. From it, retrieve the variable contents and use it

```
cmd code : set "runVar=shutdown /r /m \\%%c /t %delay% /c "%message%""
           wscript //nologo "%windir%\myscripts\runInvisible.vbs" runVar

vbs code : With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") : .Run .ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "%"), 0, False : End With
```

Comment: I opted to try your third method, but I am getting a script error. Edited my original post.

Comment: Tried the first option with no success either.

Comment: @MakoHunter, Without seeing your code i can not say why you get a error in the third case, for me it works. For the first sample, the `WScript.Echo` is what shows the popup. It was intended as a sample. I have adapted the code to your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd code or bat code:
wscript //nologo invisible.vbs "hello world" 0
```

somehow the zero on the end, causes the part between quotes being seen as one argument still